# How can I store the Android device token?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to store the device token somehow because it's possible that I need it at a later time. For example, the user starts my application and OnNewToken gets executed and I get the device token. Now I want to store the token because it's possible that I need the token again when the user restarts my application in a few days. I don't think that OnNewToken gets executed again when the user restarts my application, but I'm not sure about that? Therefore I want to store the token and just override its value if OnNewToken gets executed again to store the new token.

In, addition, I want to use the Android device token in another class, in my case Game1.cs.

How can I store the device token and get the string in another class?

I tried to store the token with SharedPrefManager, but it's not working. I get error messages and I don't know how to solve the issue:

```
SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).saveDeviceToken(token);
```

> Error CS0103: The name 'SharedPrefManager' does not exist in the current context
>
> Error CS0103: The name 'getApplicationContext' does not exist in the current context

MyFirebaseMessagingService.cs:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Util;
using Firebase.Messaging;
using ggdgdgd.Android;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Support.V4.App;

namespace Androidproject
{
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
        storeToken(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void storeToken(String token)
    { 
        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).saveDeviceToken(token);
    }

    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
        var body = message.GetNotification().Body;
        var title = message.GetNotification().Title;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
        SendNotification(body, title, message.Data);
    }

    void SendNotification(string messageBody, string Title, IDictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        foreach (var key in data.Keys)
        {
            intent.PutExtra(key, data[key]);
        }

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this,
                                                      Activity1.NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                                      intent,
                                                      PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Activity1.CHANNEL_ID)
                                  .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
                                  .SetContentTitle(Title)
                                  .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                  .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                  .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(Activity1.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xamarin.Android equivalent of `SharedPreferences` is an interface called `ISharedPreferences`.

you could like this:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (Android.App.Application.Context)            
ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();
editor.PutString ("key_for_your_token", token);
// editor.Commit();    // older APIs
editor.Apply();   // newer APIs
```

and get the Value :

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Android.App.Application.Context)            
string token = prefs.GetString ("key_for_your_token", "");
```

Comment: It's not working. I get a few error messages in this line: string token = prefs.GetBoolean ("key_for_your_token", <default value>); Error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<' Error CS8107: Feature 'default literal' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.1 or greater. Error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected  Error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'